# Counting with a complicated conditions using awk

Tags: if-statement, awk, text-processing

I have a task. I must count inner and outer water bridges from data. I want to show you how I should count them.

For example, I have a data file:

```
MGD12   SOL54  
MGD14   SOL74    
MGD10   SOL37    
MGD16   SOL65    
MGD21   SOL66
MGD2    SOL65    
MGD64   SOL74    
MGD10   SOL37    
MGD72   SOL74    
MGD12   SOL54
```

Inner water bridges are when: MGD and SOL are the same (duplicates). Outer water bridges are when: MGD is different, but SOL is the same.

For example, in the third column, I write which line is inner water bridge and which is outer

```
1.MGD12    SOL54    inner (the same in line 10)
2.MGD14    SOL74    outer (the same SOL in 7, 9)
3.MGD10    SOL37    inner (the same in line 8)
4.MGD16    SOL65    outer (the same SOL in 6)
5.MGD21    SOL66    no water bridge
6.MGD2     SOL65    outer (the same SOL in 4)
7.MGD64    SOL74    outer (the same SOL in 2, 9)
8.MGD10    SOL37    inner (the same in line 3)
9.MGD72    SOL74    outer (the same SOL in 2, 7)
10.MGD12   SOL54    inner (the same in line 1)
```

In the output, I want just the number of inner and outer water bridges. In this case, it will be only numbers 4 and 5.

```
4 5
```

I try to write a script, but I don't know what I should put in condition, maybe I should use arrays?

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{ if () inner++; else if () outer++} END { print inner " " outer}' probe.txt
```

Edit, I try to use that script, but it's not working

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'NR==FNR         {a[$1,$2]++; s[$2]++; next} 
       a[$1,$2]!=s[$2] {outer++; next} 
       s[$2]!=1        {inner++} 
       END             {print inner,outer}' probe.txt | tee probe2.txt
```

input

```
MGD12   SOL54    
MGD14   SOL74    
MGD10   SOL37    
MGD16   SOL65    
MGD21   SOL66
MGD2    SOL65    
MGD64   SOL74    
MGD10   SOL37    
MGD72   SOL74    
MGD12   SOL54
```

In output I have a empty line (probe2.txt)

When I try another scipt

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1,$2]++; s[$2]++; next} 
               {print $0, (a[$1,$2]==s[$2]?(s[$2]==1?"no":"inner"):"outer")}' probe.txt | tee probe2.txt
```

I have again empty output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a double-scan approach is easier...

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1,$2]++; s[$2]++; next} 
               {print $0, (a[$1,$2]==s[$2]?(s[$2]==1?"no":"inner"):"outer")}' file{,}

MGD12   SOL54 inner
MGD14   SOL74 outer
MGD10   SOL37 inner
MGD16   SOL65 outer
MGD21   SOL66 no
MGD2    SOL65 outer
MGD64   SOL74 outer
MGD10   SOL37 inner
MGD72   SOL74 outer
MGD12   SOL54 inner
```

just the counts

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR         {a[$1,$2]++; s[$2]++; next} 
       a[$1,$2]!=s[$2] {outer++; next} 
       s[$2]!=1        {inner++} 
       END             {print inner,outer}' file{,}
4 5
```

Comment: thank you, I try this script, but I have nothing in output. I wrote that in editied first post

Comment: you missed to provide the file twice,  `probe.txt probe.txt` or `probe.txt{,}`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfect! I mostly use file1 | tee file2 to write output to another file in awk or to save modification file > tmp && mv tmp file, but I learn new thing from you, you help me so much thank you.